# Creating interface for c++ dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I have a class that is constructed with a path to a text file. It parses the text file and stores a lot of data in various vectors and maps as its members. I'd like to share the class as a dll with users of different versions of MSVS (something that's new to me).

My original implementation when it was just for me returned the STL containers directly. After reading, my understanding is that this is dangerous because different compilers or different versions of the same compiler can easily implement the containers differently. One solution I saw was to explicitly instantiate any templates you were using and export them as well. I also had strings so I'd need to instantiate and export that since a std::string is actually an alias for a more complex template. However, even if I went that route it appears there's nothing I can do about exporting maps.

What I've done now is that instead of giving the user access to the containers, I have accessor functions that take an index (or a key for the maps, or a key and index for a vector of maps I've got) and fetch the value. All my parameters and return values are primitive types, including const char* for the strings.

Am I understanding the problem correctly, and is this a reasonable approach to it? Do I need to worry about the integral primitives in c++ not being strictly defined in the standard? I suppose I could use the std-defined integral types as well. One issue is that the user won't be able to iterate over the containers or check size. I could provide the size as a member(all the vectors are the same size), and then I guess it'd just be up to the user to provide their own vector and fill it if they want the other vector functionality.

Comment: "...is this a reasonable approach to it?" Pretty much. I don't see mention of the memory allocations and deallocations; make sure they don't cross the dll boundary (i.e. allocate one side and deallocate the other) .

Comment: I think I understand that. I'm returning by value so that isn't a problem. Except the const char*. If someone tried to delete that memory it'd be bad, right? But that'd be a problem regardless of the dll boundary, I think?

Comment: If someone tried to delete the memory, it'll be uncertain as to what happens, you can't control it. Typically you should provide a deallocation function (in the dll) for them and then you can provide a RAII class to help the client manage it.